# Error: response status is 404 - identity server 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I use .NET Core 6.0 new version, I'm trying to implement identity in my application, login works fine and register, but when I try to run part that has Role like [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")], I got error 404, any kind of help will be welcome... Down is my code
in file Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);


builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
    c.SchemaFilter<CustomSchemaFilters>();
    c.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please insert JWT with Bearer into field",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
    });
    c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement {
                {
                    new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                    {
                    Reference = new OpenApiReference
                    {
                        Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                        Id = "Bearer"
                    }
                    },
                    new string[] { }
                    }
                });
});

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(IUserInterface));
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
{
    config.Password.RequiredLength = 0;
    config.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    config.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    config.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
})
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    // see https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resources.html
    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
})
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication(); //Added
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1Cpf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured the request pipeline in the wrong order

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication(); //Added
```

You should always do Authentication first and authorization after, like:

```
app.UseAuthentication(); //Added
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Comment: Did it help?  Actually you don't need UseAuthentication at all , because UseIdentityServer adds it for you.

Comment: Yes, it works now